# Fastest way to find out the least nr of m given sets reunited include a separate m+1 set

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, greedy

The following gives a practical example:

Let's say for `m = 4`:

```
// the sets for reuniting
Set1 = { 5 , 1 , 2 }
Set2 = { 2 , 6 , 3 }
Set3 = { 7 , 8 , 4 }
Set4 = { 4 , 9 , 10}

// the set I need to form
Set m+1: Set5 = { 1 , 2 , 3 , 4 }
```

I have to find a set of indexes e.g. `A = { 1, 2, 3 }` so that `U (Seti)` includes `Set5`, where `i` is part of `A`. The cardinal of `A` must be minimal.

Comment: Really hard to understand it, what's the problem?

Comment: I don't understand a word from the example..

Comment: he has a family of sets F and a set S. Wants to find subfamily of F - G such that |G| is minimal and S is a subset of sum of sets in G

Answer (score 2):

If I understood your question correctly,

this is the [set cover problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover_problem), which is NP hard.

As a consequence, there is no algorithm which is both optimal *and* greedy. Check the article which shows a greedy suboptimal approach.

Comment: Yes, that is the problem. Thanks for the link, but that greedy algorithm seems to have a pretty big complexity, I was hoping for an innovative ideea for something faster.

Answer (score 0):

if i understood the problem correctly, here's pseudo code that returns the indexes of the sets that cover set5:

```
setTmp = set5
A = {}
foreach i:
  if (seti intersect setTmp) is not empty then
    setTmp = setTmp  \ setI
    A.add(i)
return A
```

notice that  it's a greedy approach and doesn't guarantee A being minimal

Comment: this returns a family that covers set5, but not necesarily the minimal one.

Comment: @soulcheck you are correct, i was just adding that to the post

Comment: if it doesn't guarantee A being minimal then it's not really an answer to the question.

Comment: it's an idea... you are welcome to suggest a better one.